# Is the term "smoking department" appropriate?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Is it appropriate to use the term "smoking department" to describe a specific area of the train where smoking is permitted?
I saw the expression "smoking department" on a train in China.
I would like to know if it is authentic among native English speakers.
Thank you.

Comment: Smoking **compartment** in Australia. The signs used to say SMOKING or NON SMOKING. I don't remember whether the latter was hyphenated.

Comment: Back before smoking was banned on all domestic flights in the US, planes would have “smoking ***sections***, which were groups of rows in which smoking was permitted. I don’t remember what the corresponding arrangements were on passenger trains, but it likely consisted of setting aside designated “smoking ***cars***.” In any event, *department* would not be an idiomatic way to express the idea you’re asking about.

Comment: As @Peter says, compartment, not department. Probably a translation issue for the close meanings of the two. (Compare compartmentalize, more literal, and departmentalize, more abstract.)

Comment: You'd better hurry up : "As of July 2018, twelve states have not enacted any general statewide ban on smoking in workplaces, bars or restaurants"

Comment: It would be "Smoking compartment" in the old kind of train where the carriage was divided into self-contained compartments each with typically 6 or 8 seats. By the time smoking was banned on all trains in the UK, compartment stock had virtually disappeared, and smoking was typically allowed in one carriage of the train, which would be referred to as a "smoking carriage".

Comment: No; 'smoking department' should only ever be used in English to refer to an academic or commercial department concerned with smoking… how could that fit your query? Can you cite two or three examples, was this a contrived example, or what?

Comment: I wasn't commenting against any country that speaks English.

Comment: “Smoking department” is the English translation of the Chinese phrase "Xi Yan Chu" on a train in China, which I saw with my own eyes. The Chinese railway authorities are probably trying to explain to English speakers that on certain types of train, smoking is allowed in the joints of the carriages.

Answer (score 19):

No, "smoking department" would not be idiomatic English.

As Yosef noted in his comment, this was probably a translation error confusing "department" with "compartment". The two words sound a lot alike so I can see how one would make that mistake.

A "department" is a sub-group within an organization. Like you might talk about a corporation having a "marketing department" or a "legal department". Or the US government has the "commerce department", the "defense department", etc.

A "compartment" is a section of a vehicle that is separated off from the rest. For example, if a train has separate "rooms" for different classes of passengers or private rooms that passengers can pay for, these are called "compartments". Airplanes are routinely divided into the "first class compartment" and the "economy class compartment". Etc. In the US it is illegal to smoke on trains, but I understand that when it was legal (before my time!) there were "smoking compartments" for people who wanted to smoke, to keep them separate from those who didn't want the smell of cigarette smoke.

Comment: One of the major problems with smoking compartments on trains in those days when smoking was still allowed was that many smokers disregarded the smoking boundaries, and would smoke in the non-smoking areas.  Enforcement of the policies was difficult.  This may be one of the factors which led to banning smoking altogether on public transportation.

Comment: Yes, that and the fact that train conductors taking tickets would be exposed to the second-hand smoke. https://www.cdc.gov/tobacco/secondhand-smoke/health.html#:~:text=Secondhand%20smoke%20causes%20lung%20cancer&text=Even%20brief%20exposure%20to%20secondhand%20smoke%20can%20damage%20the%20body's,the%20cancer%20process%20in%20motion.&text=As%20with%20active%20smoking%2C%20the,risk%20of%20developing%20lung%20cancer.

Comment: Tobacco smoke is persistent. I remember what happens years ago when smoking was forbidden in the Thalys train (Paris-Brussels-Amsterdam) : It took 6 months for the tobacco smell to disappear from the smoking coach located in the middle of the train.

Comment: Another common term would be "smoking section."

Comment: @Graffito An ozonator can banish the smell of the smoke in a matter of hours, even with cloth-covered furniture.  Just don't be in the room (it can damage the lungs) with high-ozone concentrations!

Comment: Fun fact: Even the hydrogen-filled airship *Hindenburg* had a smoking room.  I guess smoking was *so* popular in the 1930's that banning it would have turned away customers.  Or worse, encouraged someone to smoke surreptitiously.  It was safer to have a designated, supervised, pressurized chamber for the purpose.

Comment: Anyhow, while "smoking compartment" is valid, a "smoking section", "smoking room", or "smoking area" would be more common.

Comment: When airlines used to allow smoking at altitude, the practice was even more damaging to people's health than smoking on the ground because of the reduced air pressure. Flight attendants were found to have higher levels of lung polyps as a result of breathing other people's smoke.

Comment: @dan04 A "smoking compartment" would normally be understood to mean a separate, walled off area on a vehicle. A "smoking room" would be a walled off area in a building. A "smoking section" would be a place, probably not walled off, within some larger room or compartment where people are allowed to smoke.

Comment: @dan04 I read an article years ago about the Hindenburg that said that the smoking room was carefully designed to keep fumes and heat separate from the hydrogen so it wouldn't endanger the aircraft. I suppose in general the passenger compartments would be designed to keep out the hydrogen. Even without smoking, I wouldn't want to walk around in a room full of hydrogen. Can't be good for you.

Comment: I'm avoiding making any comments about the wisdom or fairness of smoking restrictions. Like I try to avoid making any comment about the politics when it impinges on other language questions. This is an English language forum, not a political forum. :-)

Comment: You *must* be very young! Once upon a time, in the UK,  passengers could sit anywhere on a bus and smoke their cigarette, pipe or cigar in peace. Then smokers were segregated to the upper deck of the bus, and then they were restricted to the rear seats until eventually smoking was banned on the buses, trains, taxis etc.

Comment: The compartments of an airliner are usually called "cabins" or "sections".

Comment: @Barmar I'd definitely give you "cabin". More common than "compartment". I'd quibble over "section".

Comment: @Jay Yeah. I think "section" might be a subpart of a cabin. The cabins in an airplane are divided by a curtain, but within the main cabin you might have economy and business sections.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm no spring chicken, let me assure you, but I cannot remember a time when people were allowed to smoke on the lower deck of a double-decker bus. "Smoking allowed in the upper saloon only" was the famous notice.

Comment: @WS2 I'm old enough to remember when there were smoking sections in restaurants. I forget now if that was before or after the Punic Wars.

Comment: @WS2 then my childhood memory is playing tricks on me. I think you are right, smoking in the mid 1970s was (always?) forbidden on the lower deck of a double decker bus.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Also in the 1950s, when I used to take the bus to school. That was in Norfolk, but I believe it was the same in London.

Comment: @Jay And I'm old enough to remember when it was unusual to have non-smoking sections anywhere - in pubs or restaurants. But it was not uncommon, in pubs, to see signs which said "Don't spit on the floor" -which gave rise to the Limerick *There was a man from Darjeeling, Who went to a pub in Ealing, The sign near the door said "Don't spit on the floor", So he carefully spat on the ceiling.*

Answer (score 10):

It should be smoking "compartment."

If the word "department" were used, it implies an organizational division, such as a biology department at a university, or a men's clothing department in a department store.

"Compartment" would be used for a contained space, such as that of a train car.  In a restaurant within a building, a smoking "section" would be more appropriate, and out-of-doors the word "area" might be preferred.

When one does not properly understand the words, it is easy to find the wrong analogue in a dictionary--a common source of humor for traveling English speakers.

Comment: For "the word area is more likely to be used to describe an outdoor area than an enclosed area", is there any possible authoritative reference? Or is this a convention among native English speakers? Just want to be sure.

Comment: @Jax That actually comes from my childhood memories.  Smoking is now banned most everywhere, and I have not seen a designated smoking area in decades.

Answer (score 0):

I read this question in the HNQ and immediately thought of the phrase as describing a department in a large company, that is staffed primarily by older people.

A company might have an Accounting department, marketing department, legal department, or more-specialised groups like "international regulations compliance department"

Smoking is slowly falling out of favour as generations age, so the older generations, those close to retirement age, are more likely to smoke than the younger people.

And so I would take "smoking department" as a **derogatory phrase** describing all the older workers, who perhaps have been in the company for decades, who still do things "the old way" like smoking or renting VHS tapes or similar.

Comment: It is an interesting point to analyse the expression from this perspective.